# Get Contracts Deployed Count on Quorum Blockchain?

Tags: contract-deployment, quorum

I have lost count of the number of smart contracts deployed on my quorum blockchain.

What are some negative impact/implications of forsaken smart contracts on a private blockchain such as Quorum? Other than taking up disk space on the individual nodes, are there any other negative impact?

Also, is there some way to get the number of Contracts Deployed Count on Quorum Blockchain?